# Swift Package Manager fails to build Objective-C package when public headers use angle bracket (<>) #imports

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift-package-manager, build-tools

I have an open source, Objective-C library that I maintain. It has been around for a long time, and I've always distributed it as an embeddable Xcode project that builds a framework, as well as through Carthage and Cocoapods. (The library in question is [ORSSerialPort](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort).)

I recently added support for installing it with Swift Package Manager (see this [commit](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort/commit/e8878d58cf6e16dd42516133d2ce136f25d35ee2)), by creating a Package.swift file. I was able to do so without making any source or structure changes, which was helpful because I need to continue to distribute it as a framework as well for the foreseeable future.

However, Xcode 12 included a new (or at least newly on by default?) warning when you do #import with double quotes in public headers in a framework. I had done that in a couple places, so switched to angle brackets as is correct for a framework (see this [commit](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort/commit/97a75d513ff227e0bba937f3c703ca266c629565)).

I've only now discovered that SwiftPM no longer builds the package because of that. It fails with the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/andrewmadsen/Developer/ORSSerialPort/Source/ORSSerialPort.m:28:
/Users/andrewmadsen/Developer/ORSSerialPort/Source/ORSSerialRequest.h:28:9: fatal error: 'ORSSerial/ORSSerialPacketDescriptor.h' file not found
#import <ORSSerial/ORSSerialPacketDescriptor.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[0/1] Compiling ORSSerial ORSSerialPort.m
```

One possible solution (that does work, but is kinda gross), is to conditionalize any import with an `#ifdef`, then pass in a define in the `cSettings` argument when creating the target in Package.swift, but that seems kind of gross and unwieldy. In this project it's not bad, but in another project I have many, many more headers affected by this issue.

**So, to the root of my question:**
Is there a way to convince SPM to build an Objective-C package where the public headers use <> angle brackets to include other public headers in the package?

I've already tried specifying a header search path in `cSettings`, but this produces the same error:

```swift
.target(
    name: "ORSSerial",
    path: "Source",
    exclude: ["ORSSerialBuffer.h"],
    publicHeadersPath: ".",
    cSettings: [
        .headerSearchPath(".")
    ]
)
```

(All .h and .m files are in the same Source folder.)

Comment: I wonder if you could do `.headerSearchPath("..")`. Then `ORSSerial/ORSSerialPacketDescriptor.h` would be an actual path that exists on disk. It feels a bit hacky, but might be good if you need it to remain accessible from ObjC code (apart from the test target, where you can just set `.headerSearchPath("../ORSSerial")` to make the paths work. Not sure whether `.headerSearchPath` also affects system includes, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue recently. The only way I found to work around this was to change the includes to standard user-style includes

```
#import "ORSSerialPacketDescriptor.h"
```

Of course, this breaks the header for Objective-C clients. But since Swift uses the module map, you can still use it from Swift code.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just going ahead and wrapping all such imports in a `#ifdef SWIFTPM`, then defining `SWIFTPM` in Package.swift so it's there if the code is being built by SPM. It's working fine, but does certainly clutter up imports.